# Ultrasonic HC-SR04 sensor, why does it even have a dead-zone of 2cm?

Tags: proximity-sensor

So I have a hard time understanding why the [HC-SR04](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Proximity/HCSR04.pdf) has a dead-zone of 2 cm.

I understand why, the single-transducer ultrasonic distance sensors have a dead-zone, as they need to switching - But this is not the case with HC-SR04 as it both has a sending and receiving transducer.

Anyway, if this is due to the fact, that the wavelength of 40khz is around 0.8cm and that it needs to produce 8 full impulses (see the datasheet) - Shouldn't it then be 0.8*8 / 2 = 3.4cm?

Comment: Well, perhaps the 2cm is cover to cover, but the real xmit and rcv devices are some distance behind the cover.

Comment: Each of covers are roughly 1cm tall - But when I conduct distance measurements, the 2 cm dead-zone is a thing. It does not do accurate measurements when I'm trying to detect objects 2cm from the transducers.

Comment: The sender and the receiver are also a few centimeters apart, so getting an echo "around the edge" is likely also a problem.

Comment: How long before you can see again, after looking at the sun? That nearby receiver gets quite a blast during a transmitted "ping" pulse, **and** the transmitter takes awhile to die away at the ping's end. A bit of time is required before a received "ping" is larger than the dying-away transmitted ping.

Comment: Google "Ultrasound Ringing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the physical layout and size of the transducers. Sound gets more directional as frequency rises, the received needs to be able to get the echo. Looks like the transducers are about 3cm apart (judging by the 0.1" connector). The transducers have a polar pattern which is almost certainly the cause of the range restriction.